# Issue in row grouping ag grid Angular

Tags: ag-grid

I have data in object not a string for a column in `ag-grid` so i am unable to group the rows in `ag-grid`.
Is there any ways to tell the `ag-grid` that from which key it should group all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Complex objects can be grouped by key:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#grouping-complex-objects-with-keys